# How to properly use brace enclosed initiator?

Tags: c++, c++11, braced-init-list

I have defined 3 nested structs in my project and want to create a default setup that is used by many functions.  I have tried using the following code which the IDE says should work.

```
struct xBitValue {
    size_t depth=0;
    uint64_t key=1;

    //allow comparison
    bool operator==(const xBitValue& b) const {
        return ((depth==b.depth) && (key==b.key));
    }
    bool operator!=(const xBitValue& b) const {
        return ((depth!=b.depth) || (key!=b.key));
    }
};

struct stringHeaderOption {
    xBitValue header;
    size_t encoder=0;
};

struct stringHeaderOptions {
    size_t xBitLength;
    std::vector<stringHeaderOption> options;
};

const stringHeaderOptions defaultHeaderOptions={2,{
    {{0,1},0},
    {{0,2},1},
    {{0,3},2},
    {{1,1},3}
}};
```

but I get the error could not convert `{{{0, 1}, 0}, {{0, 2}, 1}, {{0, 3}, 2}, {{1, 1}, 3}}` from `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `std::vector<stringHeaderOption>`  with an error pointing to the last `}`.

It seems there is something I am missing on how to initialize values in this way.

C++11

Comment: You don't have your compiler set to use C++11 or later.

Comment: CMakeLists.txt says 
```set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -g -Wall")```

Comment: @user17732522 That doesn't seem to be the problem. You'll get the same error with C++20 in gcc. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3cjzv3cfh) when `BITIO_ENCODE_ALPHA` etc are not defined/declared.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse What is `BITIO_ENCODE_ALPHA` etc? Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Always post complete error instead of posting a part of it.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse Please show an actual [mre], including the full CMakeLists.txt. A common problem is misplacement of these lines.

Comment: @Jason Well, yes. Obviously I took OP by their word that the macros expand to the integer literals in the error message.

Comment: @user17732522 Although clang and msvc [differ](https://godbolt.org/z/6eGK5YK18) slightly in the generated error message from gcc. In particular, they don't say `error could not convert...` at the end of their error message.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse: Please include the macro definitions in your code to make a compilable sample.

Comment: @Jason i see now error message continued off screen.

Comment: turns out issue was default values in the structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aiming for an [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).
However, **In C++11 an aggregate cannot have default member initializers - this was changed in C++14** (See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Definitions)

Your code compiles in C++14 and later. It will not work in C++11;
See it compile in C++14: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8484258abc2e02d6

It will compile in C++11 if you remove the default values you are giving to the data members of xBitValue and stringHeaderOption.
See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb49bcb837a45f89

**Note:** In C++14 and later the following compiles (in C++11 it will result in an error):

```
stringHeaderOption s1{1,0,1}; 
stringHeaderOption s2{1,0};
stringHeaderOption s3{1};
```

Therefore, perhaps you would like to only allow constructors that create structs you find legal.

Comment: thank you.  I removed the default values and everything worked perfectly.  Defaults where not needed just a habit to make sure all values are in known state.